# Best way to initialize class's inherited member var of type std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, initialization, c++11

Entity has a member var of type std::array.  Student inherits from Entity, and will need to initialize the std::array member var it inherited.  Below is the code I'm using to do this, but it involves casting a brace-enclosed list to std::array.  I'm not sure this is the correct or optimal way to do this.  Using a brace-enclosed or double brace-enclosed list without the cast results in compilation errors.  I've tried several other ways of initializing the std::array member var with no success, so I seem to be stuck with my current method.  Is there a better way to do this?:

```
template<typename... Args> struct Entity {
    typedef const char* name_t;
    typedef const array<const char*, sizeof...(Args)> source_names_t;

    const tuple<Args...> data;
    name_t name;

    //This will be initialized by derived class Student.
    source_names_t source_names;

    Entity(
       name_t tmp_name
       , source_names_t tmp_source_names
    )
        : name(tmp_name)
        , source_names(tmp_source_names)
    {}
};

//idnum, fname, lname, married
struct Student : Entity<int, string, string, bool> {

    Student()
        : Student::Entity(
            "student"

            //Now Student initializes the array, but does it by casting.
            , (source_names_t) {{"id", "lname", "fname", "married"}}
        )
    {}
};
```

Comment: As a stylistic note, I don't think `decltype` is a good substitute for some well-named `typedef` s.

Comment: I see where I could have used a typedef for the name member, but could I have done that for source_names as well??  Thanks for the suggestion by the way.  Can always use more tips.

Comment: `typedef array<const char*, sizeof...(Args)> source_names_type;`

Comment: Inheriting from STL containers is typically a bad idea since they do not declare virtual destructors.  This might work now but it's implementation-dependent and you could suddenly start leaking memory if the STL implementation changes.  Can you encapsulate instead and expose the std::array methods you need?

Comment: @James McNellis modified code per suggestions.  Thanks.

@Steve Townsend not inheriting from std::array, just trying to initialize it in Student when it was inherited from Entity.  Unless I've missed something of course (entirely possible).

Comment: @Steve: It's not implementation dependent and will always work (assuming conformance to the standard) as long as you don't delete through a pointer to the base (the dtor isn't virtual, as you noted).  Of course, deleting through a base without a virtual dtor is always undefined behavior, even if the stdlib isn't involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options, but one relies on runtime size verification.  Note the latter in my example is equivalent to a cast.  What is wrong with casting?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  typedef std::array<char const*, 3> T;
  T data_;

  A(std::initializer_list<char const*> const& data) {
    assert(data.size() <= data_.size());  // or ==
    // of course, use different error handling as appropriate
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), data_.begin());
    std::fill(data_.begin() + data.size(), data_.end(), nullptr);
  }

  A(T const& data) : data_ (data) {}
};

int main() {
  A a ({"a", "b"});
  std::cout << (void const*)a.data_[2] << '\n';

  A b ((A::T{"a", "b"}));  // might just be the compiler I tested, but the
                           // extra parens were required; could be related
                           // to "the most vexing parse" problem
  std::cout << (void const*)b.data_[2] << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

However, it looks like this data is identical for each Student object.  Why not either use a virtual method or pass a shared object to the base ctor?  You can either copy that object, *entity_data_* below—which is equivalent to your current code—or require that it outlive and store a pointer/reference.

```
struct Student : Entity<int, string, string, bool> {
  Student() : Entity<int, string, string, bool>("student", entity_data_) {}
  // the template arguments are still required in 0x, I believe
private:
  static Entity<int, string, string, bool>::source_names_t entity_data_;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with casting?  Well... nothing I guess, I just didn't know if I was missing something important, or if there was a better way perhaps.  It just seemed odd to me that I'd have to cast a brace-list to a std::array object in order to initialize it in the initializer list.  Doing that with a raw array I figured would be fine, but this is my first time messing w/ std::array vs raw arrays.  Not quite sure what no-nos to avoid.  Anyway, thanks.  If no ones sees a problem with that cast given the scenario I painted, then I guess casting is the way to go.